# Newton method non-linear systems envolving curves

Tags: numerical-methods, nonlinear-system, newton-raphson, octave

I have to solve the following system:

$$
x'(t) \times y'(s) = 0
$$
$$
(y(s) - x(t)) \times y'(s) = 0
$$
Where:
$$
x(t) = (cos(t), sin(t))
$$
$$
y(s) = (s, s^2)
$$

using Newton's method for non-linear systems in GNU Octave.
I deduce that what I have to do is a cross product, because the $$sin(x)$$ is 0 when the angle between the two vectors is 0:
$$
x '(t) \times y' (s) = -2s \cdot sin (t) -cos (t)
$$
$$
(y(s) -x (t)) \times y'(s) = 2 \cdot s ^ 2-2 \cdot s \cdot cos (t) + s ^ 2-sin (t)
$$
However, when I take the initial guess with 
$$
(t_0, s_0) = (-3, -2)
$$
iterating 10 times, I do not get the answer.
Am I right to think that way?

If so, is the cross product between two curves calculated in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analyze the problem, consider the two equations
$$f=2s \, \sin (t) +\cos (t)=0\tag1$$
$$g=3  s ^ 2-2  s \cos (t)-\sin (t)=0\tag2$$
From $(1)$, we have $s=-\frac{1}{2}\cot (t)$. Replacing in $(2)$ and simplifying, we end with
$$g=\frac{1}{8} \csc ^2(t) (4 \sin (3 t)+3 \cos (2 t)-4 \sin (t)+3)\tag 3$$ and we end with the search of the zeros of 
$$h=4 \sin (3 t)+3 \cos (2 t)-4 \sin (t)+3\tag 4$$ If we graph functions $g$ or $h$,we can notice the problem. For $t <0$, there is no root between $-\pi$ and $0$. The first one seems to be close to $-3.9$ and the next is close to $-5.7$.

If we face such a problem in $1D$, I prefer not to think about what it could be in $2D$. If you prefer to stay in $2D$, use 
$$(t_0, s_0) = (-4.0, +0.5)$$ and calculations should converge.

For the $1D$ problem, you would have a very good approximation of the roots builting the Taylor expansion
$$h=h(t_*)+\frac 12 h''(t_*) (t-t_*)^2+O((t-t_*)^2)$$ with $t_*=-\frac {3\pi}2$ where $h'(t)=0$. This would give, as *estimates*,
$$t_\pm=-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$$